# Ударение в слове вытынанка

Tags: ударение

на какой слог падает ударение в слове вытынанка?

Comment: Это легко, а что слово-то означает?

Comment: вырезание из бумаги

Comment: @11Андрей11, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вы это слово в русском тексте встретили?

Понимаете, на русском не нормируется ударение в словах, которые не зафиксированы словарями, это даже технически невозжожно.

По сложившейся практике на русском, как и на украинском ударение падает на а: вытын**а**нки.  
Обратите, кстати, внимание, что в украинском это слово обычно используется во множественном числе, логично было бы и в русском так поступать...